# How to keep track of which pages users are visiting in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

everyone!

I'm doing a little research on how to keep track of which pages are visited by users.
So my assignment is to return an error page, when the user is visiting a non-existing path on the website, with a random string. I have to keep these random-strings in a CSV file with all the explanations.

I know that I have to check for non-existing routes and generate random-strings to eventually push into a CSV file.
But I think, I'm missing something.

Can anyone explain to me what I have to do exactly?

Articles, tutorials, best practices about this topic would be very nice.

Thank you!

Comment: Some inspiration https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#http-exceptions

Comment: Ow great! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could give Middleware a look. You are able to grab the request as the user is coming in, doing so will allow you to append this to a CSV using package like [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel)

This should give you the ability to track what pages users are visiting and check if it exists first and generate a random string and abort with a 404. Take a look at the documentation on Laravel's Middleware:

[Laravel 5.4 Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)

This is one way to go about it, I am sure there are other ways as well.

Comment: This is what I need! Thank you!

Comment: @user3593591 I am not sure that you can "catch" HTTPError(s) (40X) in middleware, use global handler for that (exceptions/Handler.php), and also I would avoid catching **any** exceptions in middleware.